# Unpacking a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

How can I unpack the following list

```
[('1', 'GENERAL', '1'), ('1.1', 'RELATED DOCUMENTS', '1'), ('1.2', 'SUMMARY', '1'), ('1.3', 'DEFINITIONS', '1'), ('1.4', 'INFORMATIONAL SUBMITTALS', '2'), ('1.5', 'GENERAL COORDINATION PROCEDURES', '2'), ('1.6', 'COORDINATION DRAWINGS', '3'), ('1.7', 'REQUESTS FOR INFORMATION (RFIs)', '4'), ('1.8', 'PROJECT MEETINGS', '6')]
[[('2', 'PRODUCTS – NOT APPLICABLE', '10')]]
```

From solution on other post I tried.

```
Part, Title, Page = zip(*text_good[0])
```

But got the error

```
 too many values to unpack (expected 3)
```

And I also tried

```
Part1[a].append(Part for Part, Title, Page in text_good[0])
Part2[a].append(Part for Part, Title, Page in text_good[1])
Part3[a].append(Part for Part, Title, Page in text_good[2])
```

But this seemed to return a spot in memory and I could not open the array because I received an error stating it is not pickable.

Thanks

Update: 
Assignment of  text_good

```
for i in range(0, len(text_between_parts)):
    text_good[i].append(re.findall(r'\s*(\b\d+(?:[.]\d+)?)\W+\s*(.*?)\s*(\b\d+\b)', text_between_parts[i]))
```

Update 2: When I do text_good[0] I get

```
[[('1', 'GENERAL', '1'), ('1.1', 'RELATED DOCUMENTS', '1'), ('1.2', 'SUMMARY', '1'), ('1.3', 'DEFINITIONS', '1'), ('1.4', 'INFORMATIONAL SUBMITTALS', '2'), ('1.5', 'GENERAL COORDINATION PROCEDURES', '2'), ('1.6', 'COORDINATION DRAWINGS', '3'), ('1.7', 'REQUESTS FOR INFORMATION (RFIs)', '4'), ('1.8', 'PROJECT MEETINGS', '6')]]
```

and when I do text_good[0][0] I get

```
[('1', 'GENERAL', '1'), ('1.1', 'RELATED DOCUMENTS', '1'), ('1.2', 'SUMMARY', '1'), ('1.3', 'DEFINITIONS', '1'), ('1.4', 'INFORMATIONAL SUBMITTALS', '2'), ('1.5', 'GENERAL COORDINATION PROCEDURES', '2'), ('1.6', 'COORDINATION DRAWINGS', '3'), ('1.7', 'REQUESTS FOR INFORMATION (RFIs)', '4'), ('1.8', 'PROJECT MEETINGS', '6')]
```

Notice the extra bracket when I do text_good[0].

Comment: That's not a list. It might be two lists, or a string or something, or you could have just screwed up the text when you posted it.

Comment: What do you want `Part`, `Title`, and `Page` to be after this operation?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is a list with a tuple at each index. When I did list[0] I get [[('1', 'GENERAL', '1'), ('1.1', 'RELATED DOCUMENTS', '1'), ('1.2', 'PROJECT DESCRIPTION', '1'), ('1.3', 'OWNER', '1'), ('1.4', 'ARCHITECT/ENGINEER', '2'), ('1.5', 'PURCHASE CONTRACTS', '2'), ('1.6', 'OWNER-FURNISHED ITEMS', '2'), ('1.7', 'CONTRACTOR-FURNISHED ITEMS', '3'), ('1.8', 'CONTRACTOR USE OF PREMISES', '3'), ('1.9', 'OWNER OCCUPANCY', '3'), ('1.10', 'WORK RESTRICTIONS', '4')]]. I want the end result to be 3 separate list each having a value of each tuple.

Comment: Indeed the initial list seems wrong to me.... otherwise you could have used res = [dict(zip(['Part', 'Title', 'Page'], vals)) for vals in l]

Comment: That's completely different from what you posted, in both structure and content. If you can't provide a coherent description of what your data looks like, we can't do much to help you process it.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to python. I thought I posted a coherent description and correct data. Let me try again. How can I take the list of tuples that I posted in the above comment and separate the values in each tuple into 3 different list? So the first index of the tuples would be Position1 = ['1', '1,1', '1.2', '1.3', etc...) Thanks

Comment: I tried what @Apero posted but it didn't compute the result I was hoping for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I think we need to do a little clarification here first. I'm a little confused on what exactly the list is so I will make the following assumption (if any of these assumptions are wrong please let me know so I can fix them):

```
text_good = [[('1', 'GENERAL', '1'), ('1.1', 'RELATED DOCUMENTS', '1'), ('1.2', 'SUMMARY', '1'), ('1.3', 'DEFINITIONS', '1'), ('1.4', 'INFORMATIONAL SUBMITTALS', '2'), ('1.5', 'GENERAL COORDINATION PROCEDURES', '2'), ('1.6', 'COORDINATION DRAWINGS', '3'), ('1.7', 'REQUESTS FOR INFORMATION (RFIs)', '4'), ('1.8', 'PROJECT MEETINGS', '6')], [('2', 'PRODUCTS - NOT APPLICABLE', '10')]]
```

Where now if I do `text_good[0]` I get:

```
[('1', 'GENERAL', '1'),
 ('1.1', 'RELATED DOCUMENTS', '1'),
 ('1.2', 'SUMMARY', '1'),
 ('1.3', 'DEFINITIONS', '1'),
 ('1.4', 'INFORMATIONAL SUBMITTALS', '2'),
 ('1.5', 'GENERAL COORDINATION PROCEDURES', '2'),
 ('1.6', 'COORDINATION DRAWINGS', '3'),
 ('1.7', 'REQUESTS FOR INFORMATION (RFIs)', '4'),
 ('1.8', 'PROJECT MEETINGS', '6')]
```

and `text_good[1]` would be:

```
[('2', 'PRODUCTS - NOT APPLICABLE', '10')]
```

And to me this seems like you have a list of tuples where `('1', 'GENERAL', '1')` would correspond to `Part, Title, Page`, in that order.

Then if this is the case you need can do something like this:

```
Parts, Title, Page = zip(*[t for l in text_good for t in l])
```

Where in this case you get:

```
print Parts # ('1', '1.1', '1.2', '1.3', '1.4', '1.5', '1.6', '1.7', '1.8', '2')
print Title # ('GENERAL',
            # 'RELATED DOCUMENTS',
            # 'SUMMARY',
            # 'DEFINITIONS',
            # 'INFORMATIONAL SUBMITTALS',
            # 'GENERAL COORDINATION PROCEDURES',
            # 'COORDINATION DRAWINGS',
            # 'REQUESTS FOR INFORMATION (RFIs)',
            # 'PROJECT MEETINGS',
            # 'PRODUCTS - NOT APPLICABLE')

print Page # ('1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '3', '4', '6', '10')
```

Final Edit:
Because @JStuff has a `list of lists of lists of tuples`, we technically need 3 for loops to be able to extract the definitions he wants.

```
Parts, Title, Page = [t for l in text_good for ll in l for t in ll] # Yay for list comprehension?
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need, but it does not quite work because my list text_good contains multiple list which is what I was trying to convey with [[('2', 'PRODUCTS – NOT APPLICABLE', '10')]] underneath the list you used in your solution. When I do Parts, Title, Page = zip(*text_good) I get the error ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1). Note: text_good currently contains 3 list. If I try Part, Title, Page = zip(*text_good[0]) I get the error ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3). Does this help? I can further clarify anything. I am in python 3

Comment: @Jstuff can you copy/paste the assignment of `text_good`

Comment: This may be confusing but 
    
    for i in range(0, len(text_between_parts)):
        text_good[i].append(re.findall(r'\s*(\b\d+(?:[.]\d+)?)\W+\s*(.*?)\s*(\b\d+\b)', text_between_parts[i]))

Comment: @ZWiki posted it in a more readable way in the original post. len(text_between_parts) will equal 3 so text_good will have 3 list of tuples created. Does that clarify more things?

Comment: @Jstuff I just updated my answer to accept a `list of lists of tuples`, which is what I think you wanted

Comment: @ZWiki I still get the error ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1). I may have found the problem though, but I am unsure how to rectify it. I added an explanation under update number 2 on the original post to explain it.

Comment: @Jstuff can you chat with me here? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python